# relation not found when syncdb is run in django

Tags: django, postgresql, relation, syncdb

I have these classes in the models.py of my django application.I am using postgresql 8.3 as database

```
class Course(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Courses"

class CourseChoicesForm(forms.Form):
    courseoption = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x.id,x.title) for x in Course.objects.all()])
```

When I run `python manage.py syncdb` ,I get an error which says the `relation course is not found`

```
...
File "/home/me/Django-1.4/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/me/dev/python/django/myprj/myapp/models.py", line 50, in <module>
    class CourseChoicesForm(forms.Form):
  File "/home/me/dev/python/django/myprj/myapp/models.py", line 52, in CourseChoicesForm
    courseoption = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x.id,x.title) for x in Course.objects.all()])
...
File "/home/me/Django-1.4/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "myapp_course" does not exist
```

**UPDATE:**
I solved this as follows

```
class CourseChoicesForm(forms.Form):
    courseoption = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[],required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CourseChoicesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['courseoption'].choices = [(x.id,x.title) for x in Course.objects.all()]
```

Still,I am not quite sure why this behaviour occurred.Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not good practise to put your forms inside your models.py file, and this is exactly why.

For `syncdb` to run, it first needs to load your models files. This certainly has to happen before it can make any database updates.

Now, your models.py file *also* includes a form class, and that class definition relies on the table being present. (That's just part of the way that Python works -- your class definitions are executed at the time the module is imported). So, before the table could be added, `syncdb` had to load a module which required that the table be present.

When you changed your form class, you moved the line that depended on the new table -- now it's inside an `__init__` method. Unlike the class *definition*, that method does not get run at import time. It only runs when you actually create a form object. Now `syncdb` can import your new module and update the database, and everything works as it should.